# "Empaquetar" en el ejecutable el "tipo de fuente(letra)" Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy con un inconveniente, realice un programita con su GUI hecha en tkinter, en ella use un tipo de fuente que descargue por internet, en mi pc funciona correctamente pero cuando lo abro desde otra pc, el estilo de fuente no se logra ver. ¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera imagen es como se ve en mi pc con la fuente que utilice, y la segunda es como se ve en otras computadoras.

¡Saludos!

Comment: es medio hackish, hay q instalar temporalmente la fuente y el método cambia según el sistema operativo. ( personalmente no la he probado ) hay una extensión para win/linux https://github.com/TkinterEP/python-tkextrafont

Comment: @aloMalbarez

CREO que con ello ahora puede funcionar, pero tengo otro problema, cuando abro el ejecutable me da este error: 

"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado: 'C:\\Users\\Nello\\output\\contadorFlotante_v2\\tkextrafont' "

Comment: Tienes que llevarte la fuente contigo, cópiate la carpeta tkectrafont a tu código y haz que sea una ruta relativa: ".\\archivos_extras\\tkextrafont" y modifícalo en tu código.

Comment: @aloMalbarez Si quieres deja tu comentario (sobre tkextrafont) como una "respuesta" así la puedo aceptar! :D era justamente eso lo que buscaba, ya veré como solucionar el otro problema que tengo ahora al hacerlo ejecutable :c

Comment: @nhydawn podés "autorresponderte" y mencionar el contenido del comentario en cuestión :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"es medio hackish, hay q instalar temporalmente la fuente y el método cambia según el sistema operativo. ( personalmente no la he probado ) hay una extensión para win/linux github.com/TkinterEP/python-tkextrafont"

Gracias @aloMalbarez, con ello logre solucionar mi problema.